# Ordering VARCHAR2 dates in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in a `VIEW` that contains date values in the format of 'MM/DD/YYYY'.

If this column only contained date values in the format I listed, I could do an `ORDER BY` on the column with a `TO_DATE` on it to get the VIEW to sort by that date:

```
ORDER BY TO_DATE(MY_DATE_COLUMN, 'MM/DD/YYYY') desc
```

However, there's data in this column that's not formatted as 'MM/DD/YYYY'.

Is there anyway just using `SQL` to be able to sort on this column being realized as a `DATE` column?

I'm thinking that it's not possible due to the data that is not formatted as 'MM/DD/YYYY', but I'm not totally sure...

I don't want to add another column in the `VIEW` to accomplish this as well.

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out.  If your data isn't consistent I don't think there's a magic SQL command that will determine what it SHOULD be.

Comment: hmmm - downvotes for asking a legitimate programming question?  if the answer is "NO", then why not say that and then explain why...

Comment: For what it's worth I didn't downvote.

Comment: @JNK - thanks - my assumption is that this is NOT possible, but I wanted to see if others have run into this and found a way around it...

Comment: I didn't post an answer since I don't work with Oracle, but I will be extremely surprised.  You may be able to fudge something with `CASE` if you have a known set of patterns though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a function on this column that tries to convert the date, but catches any exceptions, and sort by that.

You can also nest the exceptions and try several formats for conversion before defaulting to some date of your choosing.  eg.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my2date( p_str in VARCHAR2) RETURN DATE is

BEGIN
      RETURN to_date( p_str, 'MM/DD/YYYY' );
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    BEGIN
        RETURN to_date( p_str, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RETURN sysdate; /* or some other fixed date - depends on if you want these first or last */
    END;
END;
/
```

Then just use the clause:

```
ORDER BY my2date(MY_DATE_COLUMN) desc;
```

Answer (score 5):

One way is to manually verify the date:

```
order by (case when substr(MY_DATE_COLUMN, 1, 2) between '01' and '12' and
                    substr(my_date_column, 3, 1) = '/' and
                    substr(my_date_column, 4, 2) between '01' and '31' and
                    substr(my_date_column, 5, 1) = '/' and
                    substr(my_date_column, 6, 4) between '1900' and '2100' and
                    len(my_date_column) = 10
               then to_date(MY_DATE_COLUMN, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
          end) desc
```

This is probably good enough for most purposes, although it will allow Feb 30th.

What you really want is the IsDate function in Oracle, but it is not available.

I realized after posting this that there might be an easier way:

```
order by substr(my_date_column, 6, 4) desc, substr(MY_DATE_COLUMN, 1, 2) desc,
         substr(my_date_column, 4, 2) desc
```

It just extracts the year, month, and day and sorts descending.  Non-dates will be mixed in, depending on what they contain.  However, the questioner seemed not to care about the order but simply eliminating the syntax error.

Comment: Thanks - this looks like the way to go - I'll experiment with it

Answer (score 2):

how about fix the data, and add a trigger to prevent further bad data... 
or add a proper date column instead of the varchar...

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to achieve this is to define your own `to_date()` function which returns null (or any other default value like `sysdate`). This is possible because `to_date` simply throws an exception when it can't handle the input value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_date_null(date_str IN varchar2, format_mask IN varchar2)
RETURN DATE
IS
  l_date DATE;
BEGIN
  l_date := to_date( date_str, format_mask );
  RETURN l_date;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN
    RETURN null;
END to_date_null;
```

Then you can use this function in your `order by` clause

```
order by to_date_null(MY_DATE_COLUMN, 'MM/DD/YYYY') desc NULLS LAST;
```

By specifying `NULLS FIRST` or `NULLS LAST` you can define where the non-date values are placed.